# Will Ubuntu 11.10 use the GNOME 3 system settings?

Tags: 11.10

If so, Ubuntu will be lack of customization like GNOME 3??

Comment: it's too warly in the devlopment cycle, for anyone to be sure of that.

Answer (score 6):

It already does:

```
gnome-control-center:
  Installed: 1:3.0.2-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 1:3.0.2-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1:3.0.2-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main i386 Packages
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/

Comment: There are still over five months to go, so I'm not yet nervous. :P